# Erro em Haskell ao usar guardas (parse error on input ´|')

Tags: if, else, programação-funcional, haskell

A primeira guarda dá erro. Já pesquisei sobre esse erro e dizem que isso acontece quando se usa tabulação ao invés do espaço pois Haskell não permite isso, ou também quando não se dá um espaço depois de inserir a guarda. Já testei as 2 possibilidades e não adiantou.

```
     min3::Int->Int->Int->Int
     min3 n1 n2 n3                                                  
                  | n1<n2 && n1<n3 = n1     
                  | n2<n1 && n2<n3 = n2
                  | n3<n1 && n3<n2 = n3                                                 
                  | otherwise =n1
```

No Haskell:

```
        parse error on input `|'
       |   
   18  |   | n1<n2 && n1<n3 = n1
       |   ^
```

O ambiente usado é o GHCI versão 8.10.6

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir seu erro. Aqui a compilação funcionou sem error. Você já conseguiu solucionar?

Comment: Não tentei de novo, mas percebi fazendo outro código que haskell reconhece certos espaços em branco de tabulação, pode ser isso. Mas não entendo por que dá erro se eu nao uso tabulação nenhuma, eu faço justamente o que Haskell pede que é usar espaços pra indentar.

Comment: @JoãoMarcelo, sua pergunta está muito vaga, forneça mais detalhes sobre teu ambiente de execução (local ou on-line), se é Haskell Cabal, ou convencional. A princípio, tua formatação está um pouco fora do padrão, como podemos ver pela assinatura quanto pela declaração da tua função. Estas devem estar sempre alinhadas à esquerda no teu editor, em vez de terem aquelas tabulações ali.

Answer (score -2):

`min3 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int`

`min3 n1 n2 n3`
`| (n1<n2) && (n1<n3) = n1`
               `| (n2<n1) && (n2<n3) = n2`
`| otherwise=n3`

Eu testei uma alternativa a este código que funcionou, que o pode ajudar.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).